# Check which 2d array elements are closer to each other if the index is represented as x y positions

Tags: c++, arrays

So I have a two dimensional array that holds some value that doesn't matter.
Let's say that the indexes represent x and y positions on a grid and that I have three points on that grid: The main point and two extra points how do I check which extra point is closest to the main point.
This is the code I tried but it didn't seem to quite work.

```
if(abs(mainX - extra1X) + abs(mainY - extra1Y) < abs(mainX - extra2X) + abs(mainY - extra2Y))
{
cout << "Extra point 1 is closer" << endl;
}
else if(abs(mainX - extra1X) + abs(mainY - extra1Y) > abs(mainX - extra2X) + abs(mainY - extra2Y))
{
cout << "Extra point 2 is closer" << endl;
}
else
{
cout << "They are equally close" << endl;
}
```

All help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: A^2 + B^2 = C^2  (a squared plus b squared equals c squared)

Comment: your conditions are identical left/right! besides there's no point 2. You're providing code to avoid being downvoted, but it's worse than not providing code at all.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre The fact that there was no point 2 was an accident but I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [The Distance Formula](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/distance_formula/index.php):

```
double Distance = sqrt(pow((X1 - X2), 2) + pow((Y1 - Y2), 2));
```

Implement and execute that for both points, then check the value of `Distance` for each point to determine which point is closer.

This should work:

```
double DistanceOne = sqrt(pow((MainX - ExtraXone), 2) + pow((MainY - ExtraYone), 2));
double DistanceTwo = sqrt(pow((MainX - ExtraXtwo), 2) + pow((MainY - ExtraYtwo), 2));

if(DistanceOne < DistanceTwo)
    cout << "Point 1 is closer.\n";
else if (DistanceOne > DistanceTwo)
    cout << "Point 2 is closer.\n";
else
    cout << "Points 1 and 2 are on the same distance from Point Main.\n";
```

Comment: As an optimisation you can avoid the costly sqrt and pow. You don't need to know the distance, just if it is less or more than another one.

Comment: @lfgtm But I think this is more readable / understandable for OP.

Comment: Agreed, just thought I would mention it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need distance but just need less or more, I want to recommend to
just use square of the two number. you can try this

```
double dSquare = (mainX - extra1X) * (mainX - extra1X) + (mainY - extra1Y)     * (mainY - extra1Y); 
double dSquare = (mainX - extra1X) * (mainX - extra1X) + (mainY - extra1Y) *(mainY - extra1Y);
if(dSquare > dSquare2)
   cout << "point 2 is closer" << endl;
else if(dSquare < dSquare2)
   cout << "point 1 is closer" << endl;
else
   cout << "two point are on the same distance from the main point" << endl;
```